# Find UMVUE of $\sigma$ and $3\sigma^2$ in which $\sigma$ is parameters of $N(0, \sigma^2)$.

Tags: statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Assume $X_1,...,X_n$ is sample of $N(0,\sigma^2), \sigma > 0$, find 
(1) complete and sufficient statistic of $\sigma^2$, 
(2) UMVUE(uniformly minimum variance unbiased estimation) of $\sigma$ and $3\sigma^2$. 
The problem is from my textbook.
Part (1) is solved, my answer is $T= \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$.

I aim to solve part (2) by applying Lehmann-Scheffe theoroem. 
I need to find a function $g(T)$ of $T$ s.t. $Eg(T) = \sigma$.

And distribution of $T/\sigma^2$ is $\chi^2_n$. Hence I get
$$
T \sim f(t) = \frac1{\sigma^n 2^{n/2} \Gamma(n/2)} t^{n/2-1}{\rm e}^{-\frac{t}{2\sigma^2}} I_{(t>0)}
$$

Therefore
$$
Eg(T) = \int_0^\infty \frac{g(t)}{\sigma^n 2^{n/2} \Gamma(n/2)} t^{n/2-1}{\rm e}^{-\frac{t}{2\sigma^2}} {\rm d}t = \sigma
$$

I got stuck here to figure $g(t)$ out. Any hint is appreciated.

---

---

By the hint of comment,

$$
\begin{align}
E\frac{T}{\sigma^2} &= n \\ 
E\frac{\sqrt{T}}{\sigma} &= \sqrt 2 \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac n2)}
\end{align}
$$
Hence,
$E\frac{3}{n}T = 3\sigma^2, E\sqrt2 \frac{\Gamma(\frac n2)}{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})} T = \sigma $.

I get unbiased estimator of $3\sigma^2$ and $\sigma$, and they are functions of $T$.

By L-S theoroem,
UMVUE of $3\sigma^2$ is $\frac3n T$, and UMVUE of $\sigma$ is $\sqrt2 \frac{\Gamma(\frac n2)}{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})} T$.

Comment: From $T/\sigma^2 \sim \chi^2_n$, you readily have an unbiased estimator of $3\sigma^2$. As for $\sigma$, find the expectation of $\sqrt{T/\sigma^2}$ using the pdf of $T/\sigma^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your hint.